# IIS https hosting - to get mmc installed certificate by code

Tags: azure, ssl, iis

I got success in checking cert is present in my current user by local execution process. But when I publish the same code on IIS, I am unable to get a certificate.
Please guide changes in code or settings for code publish on IIS.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

string certThumbprint = "E661583E8FABEF4C0BEF694CBC41C28FB81CD870";
bool validOnly = false;

using (X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
  certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

  X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                              X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                              // Replace below with your certificate's thumbprint
                              certThumbprint,
                              validOnly);
  // Get the first cert with the thumbprint
  X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection.OfType<X509Certificate>().FirstOrDefault();

  if (cert is null)
      throw new Exception($"Certificate with thumbprint {certThumbprint} was not found");

  // Use certificate
  Console.WriteLine(cert.FriendlyName);
  
  // Consider to call Dispose() on the certificate after it's being used, available in .NET 4.6 and later
}
```

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Web apps on IIS do not run under your account by default, so naturally they don't have access to your personal certificate store (aka MY) and won't see that certificate.

Comment: Thanks, Lex Li! Please guide if you know another method of implementation.

Comment: May be this link can help you: https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-install/microsoft-iis-7-ssl-installation/

Comment: Thanks for the help Theobald Du! I have used link shared by you and provided access permission to certificate for IIS_IUSRS.